# Vb.Net Scraped Data MsgBox Shows Line Breaks but RichTextBox Does Not

Tags: regex, vb.net, split, scrape

So I'm scraping data and I've got my xpath parsing out the line I need.

I go line by line and dump out the data so I know I'm looking in the right place and for every listing it's showing several lines which is good. Exactly what I expected.

Example Msgbox dump:

```
Msgbox(node.innertext)
```

Example Msgbox  Outputs:

```
Mr C Moore
10/2
5/1
17/6
```

Hit OK and the next one comes up:

```
M D Hunt
1/1
3/1
12/500
```

And it continues like that for every listing. Great.

I try to split it by environment.newline and get - nothing. Everything is on splitarray(0) so I dump the innertext into a rich text box and everything is squashed up.

Example rich text box dump:

```
rtbdump.text = node.innertext & environment.newline & rtbdump.text
```

Example Rich text box output:

```
Mr C Moore10/25/117/6
M D Hunt1/13/112/500
```

I need to be able to work with these lines individually. The Msgbox output was clearly able to do that but writing it to a rich text box was all squashed together and splitting by environment.newline doesn't work.

With regex I was able to split the names out - that's a start. But I can't get any further since the numbers have no set pattern or length.

Would appreciate anyone who can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this is a thing but apparently splitting by 'vbLf' is different from environment.newline and solved my problem.